# Enable root URL for Asymmetrik FHIR server to save Bundle transactions?

Tags: javascript, hl7-fhir, node-fhir-server-core

My team is building a health app and thus using [Asymmetrik FHIR API Server](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core). We need to save a [bundle](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html) consisting of Condition, Observation and Procedure. The bundle should create each individual object in their respective tables. But when we are using postman to hit the base URL with a very simple bundle object it is giving Invalid URL. Each service is individually working fine and able to create respective objects. How can we enable the root URL of this FHIR server?

POST URL: http://localhost:3000/4_0_0/

POST Object:

```json
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "f001",
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Observation",
        "status": "registered"
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Observation"
      }
    },
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Condition",
        "code": {
          "coding": {
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/ValueSet/condition-code",
            "code": "",
            "display": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Condition"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

ERROR:

```json
{
  "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
  "issue": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": "not-found",
      "details": {
        "text": "Invalid url: /4_0_0/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the CapabilityStatement for the server indicate that it supports 'transaction'?

Comment: And have you tried populating fullUrl - it's important for transactions